# 1Finding Segmentation in Time Series error

Tags: r, breakpoints

I have the following data:

```
Lines <- "D1,Value
1,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
2,20/11/2014 17:00,0.01  
3,20/11/2014 19:00,0.01  
4,20/11/2014 22:00,0.20  
5,20/11/2014 23:00,0.03"

library(zoo)
library(strucchange)
ts1 <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
z <- read.zoo(ts1, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

I use interpolation for filling in the missing values:

```
interp <- na.approx(z, xout = seq(start(z), end(z), "hours"))
```

I would like to find the segments (maximum 2 segments) and to draw the relevant lines for each segment:

```
interp1 <- as.ts(interp)
```

I get the following error:

```
bp.interp1<- breakpoints(interp1 ~ 2)
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

In addition the dates were changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strucchange package depends on zoo so you don't need to explicitly load zoo.  You don't need `read.table` if you are using `read.zoo` and it is not necessary to convert the time series to a `"ts"` object.  You do need to specify the formula.  See `?breakpoints`

```
library(strucchange)

# test input
Lines <- "D1,Value
1,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
2,20/11/2014 17:00,0.01  
3,20/11/2014 19:00,0.01  
4,20/11/2014 22:00,0.20  
5,20/11/2014 23:00,0.03"
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")

bp <- breakpoints(z ~ 1, h = 2)
```

giving:

```
> bp

         Optimal 2-segment partition: 

Call:
breakpoints.formula(formula = z ~ 1, h = 2)

Breakpoints at observation number:
3 

Corresponding to breakdates:
0.6
```

**Note:**  To plot:

```
plot(z)
abline(v = time(z)[bp$breakpoints])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @G. Grothendieck, Is there a way to add the lines and break point to the graph of z? I tried plot (z);a<-breakpoints(z ~ 1, h = 2); lines(a);